# How can I get solutions of this trigonometric equation?

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I am trying to solve the equation
$$\left(\sin (x)+\cos (x)-\sqrt{2}\right)\cdot \sqrt{-11 x-x^2-30}=0$$ in Real domain. I tried

***First way***

```
Solve[{(Sin[x] + Cos[x] - Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[-11 x - x^2 - 30] == 0}]
```

I got

> {{x -> -6}, {x -> -5}, {x -> [Pi]/4}}

***Second way***

```
   Solve[{(Sin[x] + Cos[x] - Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[-11 x - x^2 - 30] == 0}, x, 
  Reals] // FullSimplify
```

I got

> {{x -> -6}, {x -> -5}, {x -> -((7 [Pi])/4)}, {x -> -((7 [Pi])/4)}}

***Third way***

```
sol = (TrigExpand@
  Reduce[(Sin[x] + Cos[x] - Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[-11 x - x^2 - 30] == 0, 
   x, Reals] // FullSimplify // Last) /. C[1] -> k
```

I got

> x == -((7 [Pi])/4)

How to get the correct solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Solve gives you a warning that it may not find all possible answers. Use Reduce instead:

```
Reduce[{(Sin[x] + Cos[x] - Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[-11 x - x^2 - 30] == 0}]

(C[1] \[Element] Integers && x == -2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] + 2 \[Pi] C[1]) || x == -6 || x == -5
```

which shows that there is an infinite family of solutions, one for each integer C[1].

Comment: How can I simplify solution `x == -2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] + 2 \[Pi] C[1])`?

Comment: -2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] // N simplifies this to a number. 2 Pi C[1] is 2 Pi times any integer, so cannot be simplified.

Comment: I want your solutions should be simplified.

Comment: I used and get the correct solutions.
 Reduce[(Sin[x] + Cos[x] - Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[-11 x - x^2 - 30] == 0, x, Reals] // FullSimplify`

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - `Reduce[{(Sin[x] + Cos[x] - Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[-11 x - x^2 - 30] == 0}]//FullSimplify` eliminates the `ArcTan` and makes it easy to see that your result is just the case for `C[1] -> -1`

Comment: @BobHanlon But why adding `Reals` gives only a subset of roots

Comment: @Epsilon Please see my question. I solve the equation in Real domain.

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes. Please see my question. Only `C[1] -> -1` satifies the condition `-11 x - x^2 - 30 >=0`.  I solve the equation in Real domain.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Other roots of `bill s` are also in real domain, check them.

Comment: @Epsilon I tried with `Pi/4`. This solution does not satify the condition `-11 x - x^2 - 30 >=0`.

Comment: @Epsilon Please tried `f[x_] := -11 x - x^2 - 30;
N[f[Pi/4]]`

Comment: @minthein_2016 Ok I will check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95897/discussion-between-epsilon-and-minhthien-2016).

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - Using `Reduce[..., Reals]` restricts not only the result to `Reals` but also all intermediate evaluations, `(Sin[x] + Cos[x] - Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[-11 x - x^2 - 30] == 0 /. 
  x -> (Pi + 8 Pi C[1])/4 // Simplify[#, Element[C[1], Integers]] &` shows that there are an infinite number of real solutions.

Comment: @BobHanlon Please see at here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288383/please-explain-how-to-solve-this-equation-in-reals/3288393?noredirect=1#comment6763700_3288393

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict the solution range to `-6<= x<= -5` (from checking `Sqrt[-11 x - x^2 - 30]` )

```
Solve[{(Sin[x] + Cos[x] - Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[-11 x - x^2 - 30] == 0 // TrigToExp, -6 <= x <= -5}, x]
(* {{x -> -6}, {x -> -5}, {x -> -((7 \[Pi])/4)}, {x -> -((7 \[Pi])/4)}} *)
```

`Solve`( not NSolve!!)  gives all real solutions

Comment: Please see my second way.